# How do i prove whether the graph isomorphism problem falls under np problem?

Tags: graph, np, isomorphism

Can we consider that all graph isomorphism problems falls under NP problem? If so, how do i proved it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, graph isomorphism is in NP iff there is a non-deterministic Turing Machine that runs in polynomial time that outputs `true` on the input `(G1,G2)` if `G1` and `G2` are isomorphic, and `false` otherwise.

But an equivalent definition is that there exists a *deterministic* polynomial-time Turing Machine that takes as input the triple `(G1,G2,I)` and outputs `true` or `false`, such that the following rule holds:

> `G1` and `G2` are isomorphic if and only if there exists `I` such that the output for `(G1,G2,I)` is true, where the length of `I` is polynomial in the length of `(G1,G2)`.

Let's define `I` to be a string representation of an edge-preserving bijection between nodes of `G1` and `G2`; in other words, `I` is a "witness" for the isomorphism of the two graphs. It is easy to show that `I` is polynomial (indeed, linear) in the size of `(G1,G2)`, and that there is polynomial-time (indeed, linear) algorithm that checks that `I` is an edge-preserving bijection.

Hence graph isomorphism is in NP.